# Wrong fields reset when method SalesLine.modifiedField is called from code

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Take any sales order with a line that has fields `SalesLine.Name` and `SalesLine.ExternalItemId` populated.

Then run following job trying to modify any field not related to the two above:

```
SalesLine sl = SalesLine::findInventTransId('US01-000025', true);
ttsBegin;
sl.CustomerLineNum = 100; //any other field will serve as well
sl.modifiedField(fieldNum(SalesLine, CustomerLineNum)); //causes the issue
sl.update();
ttsCommit;
```

When the job has completed, both `Name` and `ExternalItemId` will be reset.

The issue is caused by line `this.axInventDim().isFieldSet(fieldNum(InventDim, ConfigId))` in `\Classes\AxSalesLine\isCustExternalItemDescriptionFieldsSet`, which always returns `true`.

As a result, methods `AxSalesLine.setName` and `AxSalesLine.setExternalItemId` populate respective fields with default values.

Any advice on the reason it has been coded in Microsoft this way, and the best way to fix this?

**P.S.** I narrowed down the issue to method `\Classes\AxSalesLine\setRetailVariantId` that was introduced in R2 CU7

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue on R2 CU7. The field has been successfully updated. Are you sure there is no customizations on the way?

Comment: Probably in your scenario `InventDimCombination::findVariantId(salesLine.RetailVariantId)` didn't return a record, that's why you couldn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a base bug that was resolved 4/30/15 on KB3061573.

https://fix.lcs.dynamics.com/Issue/Resolved?kb=3061573&bugId=3612128&qc=83c15cd8881ece605195acc30e039142

I think the full method fix is close to what you have, but the hotfix may also adjust other methods.  I hope this hotfix is satisfying knowing you're not crazy.

```
protected void setRetailVariantId()
{
    InventDimCombination    comb;
    InventDim inventDim;
    ;
    comb = InventDimCombination::findVariantId(salesLine.RetailVariantId);
    inventDim = this.axInventDim().inventDim();
    if(comb)
    {
        if (inventDim.InventSizeId != comb.inventDim().InventSizeId)
        {
            this.axInventDim().parmInventSizeId(comb.inventDim().InventSizeId);
        }
        if (inventDim.InventColorId != comb.inventDim().InventColorId)
        {
            this.axInventDim().parmInventColorId(comb.inventDim().InventColorId);
        }
        if (inventDim.InventStyleId != comb.inventDim().InventStyleId)
        {
            this.axInventDim().parmInventStyleId(comb.inventDim().InventStyleId);
        }
        if (inventDim.configId != comb.inventDim().configId)
        {
            this.axInventDim().parmConfigId(comb.inventDim().configId);
        }
    }
}
// </RETAIL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it! That's right, they used the same fix. The only reason I didn't add `if` conditions to the other 3 fields is that they were not directly related to the bug that was reported to me, and I decided not to touch whatever had been working fine.

Comment: This is a *great* find.  Thanks Alex.  In our case changing the order's Delivery terms was resetting the sales lines Price percentage discount.

Comment: @ian_scho - Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the postscript, I narrowed down the issue to method `\Classes\AxSalesLine\setRetailVariantId`, which was introduced in R2 CU7.

As a workaround, I have added one line to the code, it resolved the issue:

```
if (this.axInventDim().parmConfigId() != comb.inventDim().configId) // added check
    this.axInventDim().parmConfigId(comb.inventDim().configId);
```

I'll wait some time for a better answer/fix. If none provided, I will accept this answer.